# postfix content filter per domain

Tags: postfix-mta

i testing postfix for my email server.
i have to content filter all emails.

`master.cf`

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=dfilt:
................
dfilt     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=Rq user=vmail:vmail argv=/opt/test/control.sh  -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

when user sent to recipients on same domains,control.sh is one run
but  user sent to recipients different domains control.sh is run per domain.
so control.sh many runs for same email. i dont this because unnecessary work

we can control.sh is only one run one email , not all recipients domain.
i hope right explain my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you will have to catch all the recipient addresses, put them in an array and then you can handle each email depending on the domain

So in your control.sh, you can add the following:

```
cap_to_address=`echo $@ |awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}'`
to_address=( $cap_to_address )
count=${#to_address[@]}

for i in `seq 1 $count`
 do
  to_domain=`echo ${to_address[$i-1]} | grep -o '[^@]*$'`
  # YOUR IF STATEMENT 
  # For eg:
  if [ $to_domain == mydomain.com ]; then
    echo "this is my domain: $to_domain"
  else
    echo "this is not my domain: $to_domain"
  fi
done
```